# React-Redux Axios Call does not return the same data as my Postman call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios, postman

I'm currently working on an API call that works exactly the way it was intended within Postman, but when the same call is made on the front-end browser, it does not return the same data. Stack is MERN.

The very interesting part in all of this is that Axios request returns a different array of data each and every time. To help explain this, for testing purposes the database has only 4 messages to return when making the call. In Postman, all 4 messages are returned each and every time. But with React-Redux, the Axios call sometimes returns 2 messages, somtimes returns 3 messages, but never returns the full 4 messages as expected.

Edit:
Looks like this is a useEffect issue, I created a button that calls the same API request and all 4 messages are returned. Anyone else ever had this issue?

Here is the API call:

```
router.get('/all', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const lastMessagesArr = [];
    const contacts = await Message.aggregate([
      { $match: { user: ObjectId(req.user.id) } },
      { $group: { _id: '$number' } },
    ]);
    // console.log('contacts', contacts);
    // console.log('req.user.id', req.user.id);

    const getAllLast = async () => {
      for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        // let shortenedMessage;
        let lastMessage = await Message.find({
          user: ObjectId(req.user.id),
          number: contacts[i]._id,
        }).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
        lastMessagesArr.push(lastMessage[0]);
        // console.log('lastMessage', lastMessage);
      }
      lastMessagesArr.sort().reverse();
      res.json(lastMessagesArr);
      // console.log('lastMessagesArr', lastMessagesArr);
    };
    await getAllLast();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server Error' });
  }
});
```

Here is my axios call React-Redux:

```
export const getAllMessages = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/messages/all');
    console.log('res.data all messages', res.data);
    dispatch({
      type: SET_ALL_MESSAGES,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }
    dispatch({
      type: MESSAGE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};
```

And this is being called on the front-end through a useEffect hook when the component loads:

```
const AllConvos = ({ getAllMessages, message }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllMessages();
  }, []);

return (
....
)
```

Is this a browser issue? (Using Chrome as the browser) Is this an Axios issue? React-Redux Issue? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: looks very strange... for first try to use limit method for catch last message, instead request all and catch last by index 0 ( let [ lastMessage ] = await Message.find({...}).sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1) ) For second, getAllMessages returns an async function, but called syncronuosly inside useEffect, but by idia, if some data received, how it can be received partially, no matter syncronously it called or not? Try to use something like thunk, or saga

Comment: Thank you for your response here, not putting async/await this was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out- it was a async/await issue within the useEffect hook. I moved the useEffect hook from the AllConvos component to component that functions as the page of the site and called the useEffect function there. The useEffect function now looks like this:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    await getAllMessages();
  }, []);
```

If I take away the async/await, the prior behavior experienced before is replicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getAllMessages = () => async (dispatch) => {
```

The above code is a thunked action (a function that returns a function).
The way it works is that instead of an object being dispatched to the store, a function is sent instead. The redux-thunk middleware checks if it is a function and executes it with dispatch.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch(); // From react-redux
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllMessages());
}, [dispatch]);
```

The thunked action needs to be dispatched so that it reaches the redux-thunk middleware. Otherwise nothing is there to pick it up.